# Problem with Pyenv and Pyenv-virtualenvwrapper in macOS

Tags: python, macos, pyenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to create a virtual environment in macOS with Pyenv and Pyenv-virtualenvwrapper. I have other virtualenvironments created, but I have noticed the python versions inside .virtualenvs are being linked to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/`-like paths.

If I run `pyenv versions` I get

```
  3.9.12
  3.9.18
  3.10.13
```

But if I run `mkvirtualenv -p 3.9.12 env-name` I get:

```
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='3.9.12'
```

My .zshrc file looks like this:

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework"

export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
pyenv virtualenvwrapper
```

I have read the docs of pyenv an virtualenvwrapper and everything seems to have been installed correclty.